# Elasticsearch nested boolean query

Tags: elasticsearch

Does a document with brown and red scores higher than a document with brown or red only?

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "term": { "text": "quick" }},
        { "term": { "text": "fox"   }},
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              { "term": { "text": "brown" }},
              { "term": { "text": "red"   }}
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases - **yes**, it would score **higher**, if there are no other differences. The reason is that boolean query scoring is summing scores of the each other clauses.

This means, that `weight(text:brown)` will be added to `weight(text:red)` which in general would lead to a higher score.

The difference is however, that each of this weight section could be different for any of the matched documents depending on [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) concept.

Overall recommendation is the following - if you're in doubt how you get the score for the query you should use `"explain": true` in your json. This will help to understand and debug what happened during scoring.

More information on Explain API - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html